# What does the acronym DDI stand for when Xcode emit "Checking DDI symbol" when building?

Tags: xcode4.2

Please provide link(s) to authoritative sources (e.g. Apple, etc). Thanks.

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing, just started doing this recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO @MacMark's answer is wrong.

DDI probably stands for `Developer Disk Image`.

Answer (score 24):

I guess "device driver interface".

Take a look at the script:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/sync_ddi
```

Answer (score 2):

Device Driver Interface (DDI)

[Telecommunication Networks Group](http://www2.tkn.tu-berlin.de/people/handziski_vlado.pdf)

[List of Technology Acronyms](http://www.whiterootmedia.com/database/dusty_arlia/list_of_technology_acronyms.html)